# Thread getting stuck at thread.start (Python)

Tags: python

Basically, I have a program that's supposed to run after it starts a thread. I wrote some simple code to demonstrate my issue:

```
from threading import Thread

def run():
    while True:
        print('yes')



def thread1():
    threader = Thread(target=run)

    threader.start()

    print('done')


thread1()
```

So basically, console keeps printing 'yes', but it never prints 'done', so it's getting stuck at threader.start(). I need the function to continue executing it's code. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sounds to me like it printed `done` and you just missed it because it immediately got buried in a sea of `yes`es.

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments had it correct. 'done' is printed.

```
def run():
    ctr=0
    while True:
        print('yes', ctr)
        ctr+=1
        if (ctr==10): return

def thread1():
    threader = Thread(target=run)
    threader.start()
    print('done')

thread1()
```

Output

```
yes 0
yes 1
done
yes 2
yes 3
yes 4
yes 5
yes 6
yes 7
yes 8
yes 9
```